# What is the best way to apply conditional classes in Angular? What should I use ngIf or ngClass?

Tags: angular

I have a refresh icon which I used to refresh or reload the grid. However with the following code

```
<i class="fas fa-sync fa-fw" (click)=refresh()></i>
```

The icon is motionless. I found the following spinning icon but I can only find documentation on how to slow down or speed up the rotation animation.

```
<i class="fas fa-sync fa-spin" (click)=refresh()></i>
```

I google and found the only `npmjs` has a controllable spinning icon but not quite what I prefer.

I was thinking of `ngIf` or `ngClass`. On the click event which calls the refresh function to reload the data, is there a way to toggle between the two class which is `fa-fw` and `fa-spin`. Basically, the icon will spin when clicks the button and stop after the reload is done?

Any help is appreciated for a newbie. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution to your problem is to use `ngClass` directive like below. Because it won't remove the element from the DOM, it just applies conditional CSS as per your logic.

**your.component.html**

```
<i class="fas fa-sync " 
  [ngClass]="isLoading ? 'fa-spin' : 'fa-fw'"  
  (click)=refresh()>
</i>
```

**your.component.ts**

```
 this.isLoading;

 refresh() {
   isLoading= true; // make this true before calling api
  // your server call here
  setTimeout( ()=> {
      this.isLoading = false; // after loading data set it false
 },3000);

 }
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

You can Ternary Operator to achieve this

`<div [ngClass]="isLoading === true ? 'fa-spin' : 'fa-fw'">`

isLoading value has to set true before calling API. After response change to false.